# Create session but has error 'Confirm form submission'

Tags: django

so i try to make a login function with session so if people logout , they cannot back to the page before

but everytime i try to back (that has session or not) it always give me an error

```
Confirm Form Resubmission This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.
```

i dont know wheres the problem , but here's the code

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':         
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            guest = User.objects.get(username=username)
            role = guest.role
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  
            if user is not None: 
                if role == 'Business Analyst':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    return render(request,'index.html',{"username":username})
                    #return redirect('/home')
                elif role == 'Admin':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    return redirect('/manageuser/')
                elif role == 'Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    return redirect('/approvallist/')
                elif role == 'Segment Manager':
                    login(request, user)
                    request.session['username'] = username
                    return redirect('/approvallist/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password!")
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,"login.html",{"form":form})


#page when you success login
def index_view(request):
    if request.session.has_key('username'):
        username = request.session['username']
        return render(request,'index.html',{"username":username})
    else:
        return redirect('/')

#page for lock_screen
def lockscreen(request):
    if request.session.has_key('username'):
        username = request.session['username']
        return render(request,'lock_screen.html',{"username":username})

#logout function

def logout(request):
    try:
        del request.session['username']
    except:
        pass
    return redirect('/')
```

```
#lockscreen.html
<form class="form-login" method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome Back {{request.session.name}}</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="centered"><img class="img-circle" width="80" src="{% static 'img/ui-sam.jpg' %}"></p>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix">                                  
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer centered">

                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-theme04" type="button">Cancel</button>
                    <a href="{% url 'polls:validationn' %} "><button class="btn btn-theme03" type="button" >Login</button></a>

              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          </form>

#login.html
 <div id="login-page">
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-login" method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
        <h2 class="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">
          <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID">
          <br>
          <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
          <br>
           {% if messages %}
              <ul class="messages">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <font color="red"><li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li></font>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            {% endif %}

              <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" type="submit" href=""><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>          

          <hr>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

maybe someone can help me with the views? im so confused right now

P.S : i only try for the business analyst role , and dont mind about another role

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check you already have a session before post and get request. Try like this.

```
    if 'logged_in' in request.session:
        if request.session['logged_in'] is True:
            return redirect('users:list_user')

    else:
        your code here . . .
```